Is there a formula that changes cell reference from current month to the next and so forth in Excel? =DATE(2024; SEQUENCE(12);2)
I have used this formula =DATE(2024; SEQUENCE(12);2) to get a table of 12 months sequential dates. I use this data for updating validity range in Excel that depends on sequence of months from the current. I have updated the ranges well for the current month based on dates from the table, but would wish to have these ranges updated automatically.
I have this table 02/Jan/24 up to 02/Dec/24 in columns AC13 to AC24, from this would like to have cell AD4 which is equal to AC13 in Jan 2024 to automatically change to A14 in Feb 2024 and so forth.

Use the following formula in the AD4 cell:
=INDEX(AC13:AC24, MONTH(TODAY()))
.

[AD4]=DATE(2024,MONTH(TODAY()),2)

u meant : "equal to AC13 in Jan 2025 to automatically change to AC14 in Feb 2025 " right?

If you change your day argument from 2 to 1 then =XLOOKUP(TODAY(),AC13#,AC13#,,-1) should work, although the formula given by @rotabor would work and doesn't need a lookup table.
